# How to dispose DataTable in asp.net before garbage collection by the GC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, garbage-collection, datatable

My application is working 24X7 and I use DataTable for data handling.

I need to dispose the DataTable everytime. I used Dispose and Clear methods, but the content is only cleared and its instance is still in the memory when I debugged the code.

How can I remove it from memory without depending upon the GC?

Thanks in advance..

EDIT:
This is my code prototype . i have done it in two ways.

```
 1     //Methord 1
 2               while (true)
 3               {
 4                   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 5                   dt.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
 6                   dt.Rows.Add("ABC");
 7                   dt.Rows.Add("XYZ");
 8                   dt.Rows.Add("PQR");
 9                   dt.Rows.Add("LMN");
 10                   dt.Dispose();
 11               }
 12    //Methord 2
 13               while (true)
 14               {
 15                   using (DataTable dtable = new DataTable())
 16                   {
 17                       dtable.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
 18                       dtable.Rows.Add("ABC");
 19                       dtable.Rows.Add("XYZ");
 20                       dtable.Rows.Add("PQR");
 21                       dtable.Rows.Add("LMN");
 22                   }
 23               }
```

how will the datatable gets disposed ? if you check with breakpoint , you can stil see datatable 'dt' still has values even after calling dispose().even on execution of Line No 11 values are still there.i need to free that memory before execution of line 12 (or before 2nd iteration of while). what should i do here?

Comment: because my application is running 24X7 and datatable is taking lot of memory . its in a loop actually. gc will collect only on program exit, which does not happen in my application. and also i cannot wait till gc collects when memory is full.

Comment: Can you show the loop code?  That might help us see what's going on.

Comment: GC does not happen "only on program exit". I think you have some fundamental GC confusion here

Comment: Are you having a memory problem right now? Like, running out of memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set every reference to the datatable to nothing/null the underlying data can be garbage collected.  When an object is orphaned the dotnet framework will automatically garbage collect when it feels it is appropriate.

You can tell the garbage collector to collect manually, but it will only collect against objects that don't have a reference in code.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx

Summary on how dotnet GC works.
http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.com/2008/05/how-garbage-collector-works-part-1.html

If the Garbage collector isn't freeing up the memory, it probably because other objects,Ui Controls/Other business objects you might have written have references to row data in your datatable.  For example you are displaying row data, or you have pass a row into another object and it has a reference to this row.

If your experiencing ever increasing memory, you have a memory leak, i.e. you have an ever increasing number of objects that have references to them and the framework cant garbage collect this data because it thinks it is being used.  You will need to look at your code and try and figure out why it is leaking, a memory profiler may help.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.. but if at all i set Datatable=null its again left to GC. and GC performs garbage collection upon 1)program exit or 2)when memory is low.  i dont't want my application to consume all memory and free it when its full

Comment: You can call GC.collect() to kick this off manually.  But if you have a memory leak, you need to find the root cause of the problem because calling the GC manually wont help you

Comment: Garbage collection doesn't happen on program exit in the way you describe.  What you describe is a memory leak, ie memory is being consumed and it only stops being consumed when you close the application.  You need to fix the leak and the problem will go away.

Comment: i have tried an pplication to check disposing and GC using IDisposable.and what i found is gc was executing only on program exit. i have refered some docs. it says gc will free memory when memory is low. could you please help me where i went wrong..

Comment: The problem will be a memory leak.  GC will be running more frequently but it wont be able to clear out memory because there will be a reference to an object.  You need to fix the leak the GC issue is masking the real problem

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove it from memory without depending on GC. It will depend on GC when and how to free the memory. GC works in an indeterministic manner which means you can't be sure when GC will actually free the instance

You should just make sure you are not keeping any reference of DataTable when it is not needed any more. If you have done that part correctly i.e. there is no reference to DataTable unless required then you are good and leave rest on GC

Comment: what you said is correct. you said GC will works in an indeterministic manner. but as far as i know, gc will do this on program exit or when memory is low. am i correct in this?

Comment: Yes you are. I think these are not the only two times when GC will do that. I am not sure will have to read about when exactly GC fires

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it is a good design to try rebuid what the GC do anyway.
Why don't you just run a loop task which runs 24/7 that just start the Process as a new thread? When the thread is done you can destroy it and in result you don't have a memory problem.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection will be required to completely dispose of it, but if you no longer need it you can always set it to null.

```
//do some stuff with the table

//don't need it any longer so set it null
table = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the dispose method, you could always wrap the datatable itself in a using block:

```
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
{
   //Do work here
}
```

This would insure that it is cleaned up when the object itself goes outside of its scope.

The [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) itself is an obvious resource if you haven't ever used it before, but the idea is very simple.

Comment: 'using' calls the Dispose() in background.Dispose notifies GC. And GC will free memory only 1) when memory is full Or 2) on program exit. So the problem still  remains..

Comment: @Girish K G:  Calling the Dispose() method does not "notify the GC".  Dispose is like any ordinary method.  The object is garbage collected when there are no longer any references to it.

Comment: The garbage collector is a bit like a really effiecient  garbage/trash/rubbish collector in the real world.  You use a object for a period of time, and eventually you stop using it, it lies around unused.  The garbage collector comes round and tidies up every so often.  Your app is running 24/7 the garbage collector has come by hundreds of time each day and decided that this object is being used...